# JQuery, Why doesn't this show the button once the input is filled out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show/hide a button when the input associated with it is empty (search bar in this case).

I'm using this Javascript:

```
if(!$('.sb-search-input').val()){
    $('.sb-search-submit.button-search').hide();
}
else {
    $('.sb-search-submit.button-search').show();
}
```

and my HTML:

```
            <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
                <form>
                    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Szukaj..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
                    <input class="sb-search-submit button-search" type="button" value="">
                </form>
                </div>
```

The sb-search-submit button-search is always disabled and does not get enabled when sb-search-input has a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try utilizing `input` event ; `e.target.value.length === 0` at `if` condition ; `.trigger()` to call `input` event handler at `$(document).ready()` alias `$(function() {})`

```js
$(function() {
$(".sb-search-input").on("input", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
    $(".sb-search-submit.button-search").hide();
  } else {
    $(".sb-search-submit.button-search").show();
  }
}).trigger("input")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
  <form>
    <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Szukaj..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search" required>
    <input class="sb-search-submit button-search" type="button" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```